# how to export a route from osmnx

Tags: routes, export, osmnx

I have the shortest route between a pair of nodes constructed using osmnx.
Now, I want to plot such route in a "full" map (instead osmnx street map).
I suppose I need to get the (lat,lng) for each node in the route, but is there any method already available?
I've been looking for some export options but I did not found any information.

Best regards

David

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54652521/7321942

Comment: Excellent suggestion- Thank you very much!